# JSP not throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, jsp, nullpointerexception

I have controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getViewRailwayService(@RequestParam long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("railwayService",railwayServiceRepository.findOne(id));
    return "admin/railwayService/view";
}
```

and jsp page:

```
...
<title>${railwayService.name}</title>
<c:forEach var="company" items="${railwayService.companies}">
...
```

It works fine, but I confused, when `railwayServiceRepository.findOne(id)` return `null` NullPointerException doesn't throw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if a [StackOverflow wiki on Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) is a trustworthy reference *(I've been trying to find it in the official specs, no luck yet)*, but:

> EL relies on the JavaBeans specification when it comes to accessing properties. In JSP, the following expression:
>
> `${user.name}`
>
> does basically the same as the following in "raw" scriptlet code (the below example is for simplicity, in reality the reflection API is used to obtain the methods and invoke them):

```
<%
  User user = (User) pageContext.findAttribute("user");
  if (user != null) {
    String name = user.getName();
    if (name != null) {
      out.print(name);
    }
  }
%>
```

> (...) Please note that it thus doesn't print "null" when the value is null nor throws a `NullPointerException` unlike as when using scriptlets. **In other words, EL is null-safe.**

Comment: See _JSR 341: Expression Language 3.0, 1.6, "Operators [] and ."_ for part of the spec explaining this null-safe behaviour.

Comment: @BalusC If it's really null safe why do I keep getting a NPE on this line?             <P><core:out value="${someBean.someDateFormatted}"/>. This works fine on the previous line: ${someBean.id}. 
This evaluates like I expect: pageContext.findAttribute("someBean").getSomeDateFormatted()

Answer (score -4):

In `model.addAttribute("railwayService",railwayServiceRepository.findOne(id));`

whenever value is null, it will not throw `NullPointerException`, It will just pass value as null to the view.

Comment: I think Tkachuk_Evgen means in the jsp

Comment: @Sandeep Patange, that's right but when I try to access '${railwayService.companies}' nothing happens

Comment: Sorry for not giving the clear explanation, but I mean  the same what Kryger has explained.